# How to transfer all contacts from Gmail group to iCloud group on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, contacts

On iPhone I have some contacts in Gmail group, I need these contacts to appear also on my other iPhone, which has only one group, iCloud.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here - you can either keep the contacts in Google Contacts and add your Google account to the other phone so they sync, or you can transfer the contacts to iCloud. If you're only using Apple devices, my recommendation would be to transfer them to iCloud, because it's simpler to manage and works well with Apple devices. If you own Windows or Android devices, keeping them in Google Contacts will allow you to access them on those devices as well.

#### Keep contacts in Google Account

To add your Google Account to the other phone:

> 1. Open your iPhone or iPad's Settings app.
> 2. Tap Accounts & Passwords and then Add Account and then Google.
> 3. Enter your email and password.
> 4. Tap Next.
> 5. Switch "Contacts" on.
> 6. At the top, tap Save.
> 7. To start syncing, open your iPhone or iPad's Contacts app.

(from [Google Support](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/2753077))

#### Transfer contacts to iCloud

> 1. Go to Google Contacts.
> 2. Check the box next to any contact and in the top left, click Selection Actions and then All.
> 3. In the top left, click More actions and then Export.
> 4. Select vCard (for iOS Contacts).
> 5. To save your file, click Export.

(from [Google Support](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/7199294))

> 1. In Contacts on iCloud.com, click the Show Actions Menu pop-up button in the sidebar, then choose Import vCard.
> 2. Select a vCard to import.

(from [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/import-contact-information-mmfba7399f/icloud))

Answer (score 2):

At the end what worked for me is, I opened all groups (Gmail, iCloud, and other that I had) on my macbook. Then, I opened Contacts app on Mac. Then, I go to the group Gmail, click on one of the contacts and then just select all (CMD+A). Then I drag and drop all of these from the Gmail to iCloud (in the left sidebar there are all these groups listed, iCLoud, Gmail....). I do this for other groups as well, i.e. I transfer all of their contacts to iCloud. Then, I just delete contacts from all other groups except iCloud. And yes, in order for this mixup doesn't happen again, I just set the Default account on my iPhone to be "iCloud".

Comment: Excellent. Just what I needed.

Comment: "And yes, in order for this mixup doesn't happen again, I just set the Default account on my iPhone to be "iCloud"." how do you do that?

Comment: @alex intersting question. There was such option somewhere in previous versions of  iOS (not sure if exists still), so to set default account for newly created contacts....not sure any more how to get to that though.